# How to remove usage of excess keyframes by using animation-delay?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm looking through Google Polymer's source code and I found this:

```
/**
 * IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT CSS ANIMATION PROPERTIES (keanulee):
 *
 * iOS Safari (tested on iOS 8.1) does not handle animation-delay very well - it doesn't
 * guarantee that the animation will start _exactly_ after that value. So we avoid using
 * animation-delay and instead set custom keyframes for each color (as redundant as it
 * seems).
 *
 **/
.active .spinner-layer.blue {
  -webkit-animation: blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.active .spinner-layer.red {
  -webkit-animation: red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.active .spinner-layer.yellow {
  -webkit-animation: yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.active .spinner-layer.green {
  -webkit-animation: green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blue-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  26% { opacity: 0; }
  89% { opacity: 0; }
  90% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes blue-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  26% { opacity: 0; }
  89% { opacity: 0; }
  90% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes red-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  15% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  51% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes red-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  15% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  51% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  76% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes yellow-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  76% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes green-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  65% { opacity: 0; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  90% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes green-fade-in-out {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  65% { opacity: 0; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  90% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

I agree that this code looks incredibly verbose, but I wasn't sure how one would go about re-expressing it using animation-delay instead of custom keyframes.

Not all the colors seem to take a full 25% chunk. Green only takes 15%... which seems a bit odd. Nevertheless, would it be as simple as just taking the start % and multiplying it by the animation duration and setting that as the delay? How would the end-time be specified, then?

How would this code look if the bug fix did not need to be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somebody has changed the code after the initial comments.

as it is now, only 2 animations are redundant, so the comment doesn¡t make full sense.

It is a common practice in cyclic animations, where in your case 4 elements share - or should share- the same animation, but in a *sequential* way, to reuse the animation and change only the start time (thru the initial delay property)

In this case, that would be probably

```
@keyframes red-fade-in-out {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  26% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

and then every class would have a different delay, of 1/4 of the total time of the animation.